# Golden rectangles construction from a square.

Tags: geometry

A golden rectangle is an a×b rectangle in which the ration $b/a = (1+\sqrt5)/2$

Let ABCD be a square. Let M be the midpoint of AB.

Draw a circle with radius MC
and centre M.

Extend the line AC past C to meet the circle in F. Let G be the point
where the perpendicular to AF at F meets the extension of DC.

Prove that AFGD
and BFGC are both golden rectangles.

To be completely honest i can't even draw the picture of the golden rectangles the instructions do not appear to make sense and i have tried a few times.

Comment: I agree – it makes no sense. The circle with radius MC, center M, goes through C, so the line AC meets the circle at C, and doesn't meet it anywhere past C. I don't know where the mistake is, but there certainly is one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change “... $AC$ past $C$...” to “... $AB$ past $B$...”

[image]